# Google Analytics for Rest APIs WSO2 Cloud API

Tags: wso2-cloud

I was following the below blog and was trying to execute the POC but no luck. i did follow all the steps as suggested however I could not see any report in google analytics after saving the content. No user is shown in report. Please suggest what could be wrong in my implementation.

[Reference Link](http://wso2.com/blogs/cloud/google-analytics-for-rest-apis/)

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to give a generic answer without looking into the configuration. I just followed the tutorial myself and it all worked fine (to test, I was making curl calls in the terminal window at my laptop and watching Real-Time / Overview report in Google Analytics.)

First and foremost, please check that _system/governance/apimgt/statistics/ga-config.xml has Enabled set to **true**, and TrackingID set to the UA- tracking code you got from GA.

One thing to check is whether you are looking at Real-Time report or historical. When you just implemented the change - look at Real-Time / Overview report initially as it starts showing data much faster.

Also, since [API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud) has multiple gateway nodes, it takes time for the configuration changes to propagate. So one thing to try is to wait 15 minutes or so from the time you applied configuration changes in the cloud, and then try invoking the API and see if the sessions are reflected in Google Analytics.

Finally, if these do not help, just [submit the support ticket in API Cloud](https://cloudmgt.cloud.wso2.com/cloudmgt/site/pages/contact-us.jag) - support is included for free with the cloud service.